# Testing for HTTPS in the end of development

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently starting a web project and I was thinking developing everything and then at the end, test in HTTPS. I am not well-versed with how HTTPS works so I wanted to ask if this is something that is OK to do. Or should I start developing using HTTPS from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave HTTPS piece of work for the later part (i.e., deployment/ hosting). For development, it is OK to use http protocol. When you deploy your website on IIS, you need to configure it to enable HTTPS protocol.